# Selenium ChromeDriver not running with desktop VPN running

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

While running Cyberghost 8 VPN, using C#, Selenium ChromeDriver no longer works and produces the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:29885/'
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the localhost port changing while using a VPN, but I can't find any good information online on how to fix this.

It works fine while VPN isn't running. Not really much I could try with the limited information online